# C - How to locate temp files previously created by tmpfile()?

Tags: c, fork, temp

I'm working on a multi-process program which basically perform fuzzification on each layer of a RVB file. (1 process -> 1 layer). Each child process is delivering a temp file by using the function: `tmpfile()`. After each child process finishes its job, the main process has to read each temp file created and assemble the data. The problem is that I don't know how to read each temp file inside the main process since I can't access to child's process memory so I can't know what's the temporary pointer to the temp file created!

Any idea?

Don't hesitate to ask for clarifications if needed.

Comment: My first suggestion is to use threads? However, yes, more clarification is needed.

Comment: Is RVB Rhino 3D Visual Basic?  Or something else?  Just curiosity...

Comment: @Jonathan: Not at all, some code written manually in C nothing more :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call `tmpfile()` in parent process, child will inherit all open descriptors and will be able to write to the file, and opened file will be accessible for parent as well.

Answer (score 4):

The `tmpfile()` function returns you a `FILE` pointer to a file with no determinate name - indeed, even the child process cannot readily determine a name for the file, let alone the parent (and on many Unix systems, the file has no name; it has been unlinked before `tmpfile()` returns to the caller).

```
extern FILE *tmpfile(void);
```

So, you are using the wrong temporary file creation primitive if you must convey file names around.

You have a number of options:

1. Have the parent process create the file streams with `tmpfile()` so that both the parent and children share the files.  There are some minor coordination issues to handle - the parent will need to seek back to the start before reading what the children wrote, and it should only do that after the child has exited.
2. Use one of the filename generating primitives instead - `mkstemp()` is good, and if you need a FILE pointer instead of a file descriptor, you can use `fdopen()` to create one.  You are still faced with the problem of getting file names from children to parent; again, the parent could open the files, or you can use a pipe for each child, or some shared memory, or ... take your pick of IPC mechanisms.
3. Have the parent open a pipe for each child before forking.  The child process closes the read end of the pipe and writes to the the write end; the parent closes the write end of the pipe and arranges to read from the the read end.  The issue here with multiple children is that the capacity of any given pipe is finite (and quite small - typically about 5 KiB).  Consequently, you need to ensure the parent reads all the pipes completely, bearing in mind that the children won't be able to exit until all the data has been read (strictly, all but the last buffer full has been read).
4. Consider using threads - but be aware of the coordination issues using threads.
5. Decide that you do not need to use multiple threads of control - whether processes or threads - but simply have the main program do the work.  This eliminates coordination and IPC issues - it does mean you won't benefit from the multi-core processor on the machine.

Of these, assuming parallel execution is of paramount importance, I'd probably use pipes to get the file names from the children (option 2); it has the fewest coordination issues.  But for simplicity, I'd go with 'main program does it all' (option 5).

Comment: how exactly does mkstempt work? when i created a temporary file on parent process, and write in it. After, i want to acces the file from child process. How can i do, can you give a small example please?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean `mkstemp()`. The [`mkstemp()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mkstemp.html) function both returns an open file descriptor and modifies the file name template passed as a parameter (don't try passing a string literal).  You can relay the file name from the parent to the child using whatever communication mechanism you've set up. There are endless possibilities — using a pipe, shared memory, a message queue, a file with a known name, or whatever. If the child is started after the parent creates the temporary file, the child has access to the name.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I want to look up on shared memory and message queue method, is it possible to give me some links?

Comment: It's probably simplest to search SO.  Suggested searches: '`[c] shared memory`' and '`[c] message queue`'. There are two shared memory systems, and two message queue systems — the System V IPC systems (`shmatt()`, `msgget()`, et al), and the more recent POSIX systems (`shm_open()`, `mq_open()`, et al). You could add one or more of those names to the search strings. If the child is started after the parent creates the temporary file, the child has access to the name. If you execute another program, the name could be passed as an argument. If you don't execute a program, the name's there to use.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a tempfile in the parent process and then fork, then have the child process use that.

Answer (score 1):

The child process can send back the filedescriptor to the parent process.

EDIT: example code in [APUE](http://www.apuebook.com/) site (src.tar.gz/apue.2e/lib, recvfd.c, sendfd.c)

Answer (score 0):

Use threads instead of subprocesses? Put the names of the temporary files in another file? Don't use random names for the temp files, but (for example) names based on the pid of the parent process (to allow several instances of your program to run simultaneously) plus a sequential number?